# AngularJS : databinding in isolated scope of directive, using an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a quite hard time to build a (maybe non-trivial) directive for an SPA. Basically I need to be able to pour data into the directive from any controller and the directive is supposed to show a live graph.

I've read [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) and I would like to use a shared object on the isolated scope of this directive anyway.

So I tried to do smth like this:

Wrapping template:

```
<div ng-controller="WrappingCtrl">
    <timeline-chart d3API="d3API"><timeline-chart>
</div>
```

In the 'wrapping' controller:

```
$scope.d3API = {};
$scope.d3API.options = {}; //for d3Config
$scope.d3API.currentValue = 3; //asynchronous!!!
```

Finally to use the shared object `d3API` in the directive's link method I tried **e.g.** this:

```
//in the directive:
scope: { //nice, but does it help??
    d3API: '='
}
```

and:

```
var data = [1, 2];
var updateTimeAxis = function() {
    var newValue;
    if (data.length) {
        newValue = (data[data.length - 1] !== scope.d3API.currentValue) ? scope.d3API.currentValue : data[data.length - 1];
        data.push(newValue);
    } else {
        console.warn('problem in updateTimeAxis: no data length');
    }
};
```

To gain some simplicity for this question I've created a fiddle, note, that none of both are working:

http://jsfiddle.net/MalteFab/rp55vjc8/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/MalteFab/rp55vjc8/5/

The value in the directive's template is not updated - what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle mostly works, you just need to update your controller to use `$timeout`:

```
app.controller('anyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    show('anyCtrl');
    $scope.bound = {};
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.bound.says = 'hello';
    }, 200);
});
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wvt1f1zt/

Otherwise no digest occurs so angular doesn't know something changed.  Based on what you're actual problem is, I'm assuming you're not using timeout vs $timeout, but if your coding style is to intermix angular with "normal" javascript, you may be running into the same kind of scenario.

A good article for reference for telling angular about what your doing is here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: ah, good point! My problem is, that the aequivalent for `bound` is not 'applied' by angular. Instead I get this error: `Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'timelineChart' is non-assignable!` Angulars docs regarding this error are not that telling - I promise, that I do use my needed attribute in the directive's element, like shown in the code above.

Comment: Perhaps post a minimal snippet that reproduces that error?

Comment: this one: http://jsfiddle.net/MalteFab/4qsL8gLo/1/ - although the error message is only similar to the cited one.

Comment: or this one (changed slightly): http://jsfiddle.net/MalteFab/4qsL8gLo/2/

I already guess, that is is a trivial error / typo???

Comment: Trivial error: element-tag variable names have to be lowercase. Fixed dAPI to d-api. http://jsfiddle.net/t59bekab/